# Error while Initialization of character array

Tags: c, arrays

I initialized my array like this:
    `char x[]={'m'};`

It worked.
But for the following lines i got error:Size of the type is unknown or zero

```
char x[][]={{'m'},{'m'}};
```

or

```
char x[][]={{'m'}};
```

I am unable to find the reason of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [row major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) architecture, you should specify at least the number of columns. Why? Because, when you assign the values, the compiler has no idea how to assign them in the 2D array.

So, as others have already said, try this:

```
char x[][1]={{'m'}};
```

or

```
char x[1][1]={{'m'}}; // note: specifying the number of rows is redundant
```

Answer (score 1):

While defining a 2D array, specifying the column size is mandatory.

```
char x[][1]={{'m'}};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the number of columns. The compiler calculates the number of rows:

```
char x[][1]={{'m'},{'m'}};
```

Answer (score 0):

In c you must specify the right most array size, so putting

```
char x[][1];
```

would work

Comment: thanks..It works..Is there any reason behind specifying right most array size?

Comment: Its so that the computer knows roughly how much memory to allocate

Comment: @QuinnFTW, That can be figured out from what you initialize it with. What can't be figured out on a general basis is the number of rows and columns.